# Is it possible to (legally) download the latest iPod firmware without owning the actual device?

Tags: ios, ipod

I think the question says it all, but: I'm looking for a way to legally download the most current iPod firmware for free, without owning an iPod. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: What do you hope to do with this software? Legally downloading it is one thing, but in most cases, Apple software is only licensed to be *used* with Apple hardware.

Answer (score 2):

Search for "iOS {your desired version} direct download" and you'll find links. Here's one for 4.3.4:

http://www.redmondpie.com/download-ios-4.3.4-for-iphone-4-3gs-ipad-2-1-and-pod-touch-direct-links/

Comment: @cksum How is the link provided distribution of illegal software? The links are public links to the IPSWs on Apple's servers (appldnld.apple.com)

Comment: @grgarside Possibly because it has information about jailbreaking in the post I linked to, despite the links being downloads direct from Apple.